# Asking for clarification or futher explanation when post is edited

Tags: support, edits

After answering a question and it gets marked that somebody has edited it, why can you not ask why? Perhaps the person editing should give a reason that gets emailed.

Why is this not done - as somebody who may be malicious could put words in your mouth.

Comment: Wow, @Gilles, despite 3 earlier edits we missed the erroneous tags! Nice edit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can look at the revision comment (and history) by clicking [the time](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/104210/revisions) after "edited":

[image: screen shot of where to click for revision history]

If that doesn't explain it: you can [leave a *@user* comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work) for the editor.

As for "put words in your mouth": [Other people can edit my posts?!](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#editing)

Answer (score 4):

When the answer is edited, the reason may be entered, and it's visible in responses tab. Example:

> Used the official name of Stack Overflow -see https://stackoverflow.com/legal/trademark-guidance, "Proper Use of the Stack Overflow and Stack Exchange Name"

The fact that the default `added X characters in body` is often used is another topic.